# Can a specific character stop data insertion using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8

I do a daily import of data (approx 62K records) using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from a text file. (via cron)

It stops loading after record 164. Looking at record 165 I found a field had the registered trademark symbol as part of a company name. ®

Could this be what is stopping the rest of the insert?

If this is a character set issue, which charset should I change the table to so it can accommodate these chars? It is currently utf8.

Comment: what says **show variables like 'character_set_filesystem';** binary ?

Comment: MySQL Reference Manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html > The server uses the character set indicated by the `character_set_database` system variable to interpret the information in the file. `SET NAMES` and the setting of `character_set_client` do not affect interpretation of input. If the contents of the input file use a character set that differs from the default, it is usually preferable to specify the character set of the file by using the `CHARACTER SET` clause. A character set of `binary` specifies “no conversion.”

Comment: @spencer7593 aha!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using CHARACTER SET binary. All records loaded successfully.